# How to create rows and column using Reactjs and Bootstrap grid system

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJs, I am trying to learn how to use the map function to create dynamic Rows and Columns using bootstrap. I am using react js bootstrap library and also installed bootstrap 5. I want to achieve the below markup in reactjs:

```
<Container>
   <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>1 of 2</Col>
        <Col>2 of 2</Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col>1 of 3</Col>
        <Col>2 of 3</Col>
        <Col>3 of 3</Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
</Container>
```

What I want is to have

```
data.map(p =>{
   <Row>
        <Col md={3}>p.something</Col>
   </Row>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the format of your data. For instance, if you have data such as:

```
const data = [
  { rowId: 1, cols: [{ id: 11, name: 'one-a'}, { id: 12, name: 'one-b'}] },
  { rowId: 2, cols: [
    { id: 21, name: 'two-a'}, { id: 22, name: 'two-b'}, { id: 23, name: 'two-c'}
  ] },
]
```

Your render function could render that markup using the following snippet:

```
data.map(p => (
   <Row key={p.rowId}>
        {p.cols.map(c => <Col md={3} key={c.id}>{c.name}</Col>)}
   </Row>
))
```

Demo:

```js
function Demo(props) { return <div>{props.children}</div> }
const Row = Demo, Col = Demo, Container = Demo;

function App() {
  const data = [
    { rowId: 1, cols: [{ id: 11, name: 'one-a'}, { id: 12, name: 'one-b'}] },
    {
      rowId: 2,
      cols: [{ id: 21, name: 'two-a'}, { id: 22, name: 'two-b'}, { id: 23, name: 'two-c'}]
    },
  ];
  return (
    <Container>
      <Container>
        {data.map(p => (
          <Row key={p.rowId}>
            {p.cols.map(c => <Col md={3} key={c.id}>{c.name}</Col>)}
          </Row>
        ))}
      </Container>
    </Container>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```